# Output voltage of this filter

Tags: operational-amplifier

I designed the following circuit so that the output voltage is Vout = 0.625V. But after actually building the circuit and testing I get Vout = 0.95V.

[image]

So obviously I was wrong but I can't manage to get the computation right, can you put me on the good track? How to get this Vout = 0.95V?

[OP284 Datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP184_284_484.pdf)

Comment: Is the op-amp rail-to-rail on the output?

Comment: Add link to datasheet to your question. And then read it.

Comment: I made a typo, it's OP284 and not OP280. I edited and added the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect an output of about 1.01 V for your circuit.

Taking KCL at the op-amp's inverting input, you have

$$I({\rm R3}) = I({\rm R2})$$

where both currents are taken as flowing from right to left. Assuming the inverting input is driven to be equal to the non-inverting input by negative feedback and applying Ohm's law, we have

$$\frac{V_o - 1.65}{390}=\frac{1.65-3.3}{1000}$$

where \$V_o\$ is the voltage at the op-amp's output terminal.

Solving this, \$V_o=1.0065\ {\rm V}\$.

Possibly your 3.3 V source has enough equivalent output resistance to disturb this equation and give the 0.95 V you measured. But in any case, that is much closer to the expected value than 0.625 V is.

Comment: Solving your equation I find 2.3V and not 1.0065V. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Try the math again, I get \$V_o=(1.65-3.3)\frac{390}{1000}+1.65 = 1.0065\$.

Comment: Tested and approved. It works fine!